# Access my account only to the previous Bitcoin URI number

Tags: bitcoin-core

'
I entered the https://bitcoincore.org site, made the downloads and installed my wallet, which was working but did not back up. He gave a problem on my PC and I had to format the drive. I re-download and now I'm using the new URI Bitcoin number .How can I access my account only password and to the previous Bitcoin URI number?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to inform you, but you cannot. If you've lost the data of the previous installation without a backup, the money is gone. You need access to the private keys stored in `wallet.dat` to spend money received to those addresses.